# Please change the blog to show posts by date

Tags: bug, blog

https://stackoverflow.blog/

The new very important blog post about the CoC changes is in the **fifth position** on the blog.

Please fix the blog to show posts by date. As pretty much every other blog I've ever seen does.

I cannot conceive of a good reason why those four posts should be above the new post.

Also the "Most Recent" is definitely not showing the most recent blog posts. It's showing posts from September even though there have been at least seven posts from October!

Comment: I'll upvote this. I had to scroll down four posts to find the newest post from today (the changing the CoC one).  It's almost like it was being buried.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I didn't want to post the snarky reason why they should be above the new post: that SE don't actually want us to read it.

Comment: I actually scrolled past it and missed it completely, thinking that the link to the blog post was some kind of divider because it had a grey highlight, a short title, and no image.

Comment: I consider this more of a bug than a feature request.

Comment: I would perhaps list the order of the five posts, I posted them in a comment below. Along with the observation that the article itself does not have an accompanying image.

Answer (score 2):

So the [blog homepage](https://stackoverflow.blog/) now does clearly label some posts as "featured", and as far as I can tell the rest are strictly ordered by date.

But this new blog homepage is not good for so many other reasons.

Let's start with the four column ad at the top.

Next, why are two tutorials on react featured? Have SE run the numbers to determine that we all need to learn react?

While the new ad at the top is tagged "partner-content", most of the other ads are not.

But here's one good thing: the podcast posts are now all grouped together. The two series of link roundups are not however.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is sorted by date, most recent first.

There's just 4 'featured' posts before it. That's not uncommon for blogs to have those, the new Code Of Conduct announcement should maybe be featured to be at top.

Comment: Why is it the only entry without an image, it's very easy to miss.

Comment: I assume (I may be wrong), they just didn't took time to find an image to illustrate this post.

Comment: I checked: The first post under FEATURED is  **1**. *Lessons from Design School for Software Engineers*
by Iheanyi Ekechukwuon **October 9**, 2019 The second is **2**. *Adding Static Code Analysis to Stack Overflow* by Kevin Montroseon **October 8**, 2019 The 3rd one in the list is **3.** Einstein Analytics and Go* by Guillaume Le Stumon **October 7**, 2019 The 4th post is: **4**. *Five Pitfalls To Avoid When Outsourcing Software Development* by Rahul Varshneyaon **October 1**, 2019

Comment: The fifth post is: **5.** *Iterating on Inclusion* by Sara Chippson **October 10**, 2019. It does not have an image. The ordering makes no sense.

Comment: The 4 first posts are featured, in most recent featured first, then 'normal' posts most recent first. I've no idea how many posts can be featured, I agree Sara's post should be featured to be on top

Comment: The only way to tell when the 'featured' list stops seems to be by looking for a backwards-jump in the dates, which is unhelpful. There should be some indication where those end, if they really need to be highlighted at all; and personally I think the 'featured' ones should then *also* appear in the subsequent list of recent entries, in date order. (I'm not sure why any of these have images, they don't seem to add anything as they're almost all generic, and the two that aren't generic could just be in the articles. The title should be enough to make me click through.)

Comment: @Alex well, I'm still guessing, but I feel it's usual to have an image with posts. Usually those without are published in a hurry but I was just aiming at the root of the question: the blog is in chronological order, most recent first. The problems comes from Sara's post which looks like an outlier in formating and being not featured while very important for us

Comment: I've since seen non-featured posts without images also show out of order, so the image isn't a relative factor.

Comment: @curiousdannii yep, I don't think the image play a role out of 'hidding' the post in the list as it stand out less without image